# Compare Nested Means

Tags: multilevel-analysis, nested-data

I have nested data and am trying to compare the means between two groups. I'm trying to compare student outcome data between two groups, those whose teachers used instructional strategy A, and those whose teachers used instructional strategy B. Obviously students need to be nested within teachers as there may be other teacher-level factors influencing outcomes. How would I compare the scores of students receiving strategy A to students receiving strategy B? I know how to use HLM to determine if it is a factor, but not how to directly compare the means and determine which method was more effective.